# Copying Cell with formatting from excel file to word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to write a **Word macro** which takes data from an **Excel** Cell and replaces a words in a **Word** file with this taken data.

My first problem was to replace more than 250 chars, which I fixed.
But this resulted in a new problem.
The data in the Excel file is formatted and this formatting gets destroyed once I **replace** the word in the Word document.

My replace function looks like this:

```
Sub ReplaceText(strSearch As String, strReplace As String)
    Dim sSplit As String: sSplit = "<Å*Å>"
    Dim sLeft As String
    Dim sLarge As Boolean: sLarge = True

    Do While sLarge = True
        If Len(strReplace) > 251 Then
            sLeft = Left(strReplace, 250) & sSplit
            strReplace = Right(strReplace, Len(strReplace) - 250)
            Call Split_Replace(strSearch, sLeft)
        ElseIf Len(strReplace) <= 251 Then
            Call Split_Replace(strSearch, strReplace)
        sLarge = False
        End If
        strSearch = sSplit
    Loop
End Sub

Sub Split_Replace(strSearch As String, strReplace As String)
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = strSearch
        .Replacement.Text = strReplace
        .Forward = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub
```

And I call it this way:

```
Call ReplaceText("intro", MyWB.Sheets(Geschlecht).Cells(7, 4)
```

But everything like (bold, italic, underline, numbering, etc.) gets removed.
If I use a MsgBox to show me the data he got from the excel cell, it is formated in the right was:
for example in the Replace Function

```
MsgBox strReplace
```

Shows the right formatting.

I hope one of you guys know how to fix this or could give me a tip in the right direction.

Greetings Lars

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by formatting when you say "If I use a MsgBox to show me the data he got from the excel cell, it is formated in the right was". A `MsgBox` certainly will *not* show any of the formatting you complain about losing: "bold, italic, underline, numbering, etc". You could try *copying* the Excel content then using `^c` as the Replacement.Text which should insert the content of the clipboard...

Comment: You are right, i made a mistake. The `MsgBox` does not show _italic_ or **bold**. But the `MsgBox` does display the newlines and the bulletpoints for the enumerations correctly, which are not displayed correctly in the word document. The Newline after every bulletpoint get's removed after the replace.

Comment: And did you try what I proposed? Anything in a string simply cannot contain formatting. Newlines and bullet points are *characters*, not formatting, and will therefore be part of the string. Word's Find/Replace can replace with formatting, but the formatting must be specified as individual properties (Replacement.Font.Name, etc.), not as part of the Replacement.Text string.